# How to resize image for Secondary Tile in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I Used this below code when i run this code Tile Created Successfully but tile not showing full image it shows Zoom image how to Resize image for Secondary tile Please Help me....

```
 SecondaryTile _tile;
    public async void createtile()
    {
        Uri squareTileUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/1.jpg");
        Uri wideTileUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/2.jpg");

        _tile = new SecondaryTile("4455",
                                        "Devi",
                                        "devi",
                                        "devi",
                                        TileOptions.ShowNameOnWideLogo | TileOptions.ShowNameOnLogo,
                                        squareTileUri,
                                        wideTileUri);
        bool status = await _tile.RequestCreateAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Can you manually resize/crop the images to the correct aspect ratio? The wide tile is 310x150 and the square tile is 150x150.  You should go for double these sizes though due to scaling on some phones.

Comment: How to resize image using code..(Because i used same image in my app in another place..)

Comment: You can use BitmapEncoder & Bitmapbounds to crop an image. How many images do you have in total? Can you not just keep multiple versions of the image in your assets folder?

Comment: @DeviPrasad Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Felix yes..but that is long process..

Comment: @DeviPrasad Haha, ok ok.